# JPA: how to override column names of @Embedded attributes

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

`Person` class

```
@Embeddable
public class Person {
    @Column
    public int code;

    //...
}
```

is embedded inside `Event` twice as two different attributes: `manager` and `operator`

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "manager_code")
    public Person manager;

    @Embedded
    @Column(name = "operator_code")
    public Person operator;

    //...
}
```

This should give two respective columns when generating database schema with Persistence. Instead an exception is thrown:

> org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: Event column: code

**How to override default column name `code` for each attribute?**

Comment: Use `@AssociationOverrides` (for entity relations) or `@AttributeOverrides` (for simple attributes)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Use [`@AttributeOverride`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/AttributeOverride.html), here is an example

```
@Embeddable public class Address {
    protected String street;
    protected String city;
    protected String state;
    @Embedded protected Zipcode zipcode;
}

@Embeddable public class Zipcode {
    protected String zip;
    protected String plusFour;
}

@Entity public class Customer {
    @Id protected Integer id;
    protected String name;
    @AttributeOverrides({
        @AttributeOverride(name="state",
                           column=@Column(name="ADDR_STATE")),
        @AttributeOverride(name="zipcode.zip",
                           column=@Column(name="ADDR_ZIP"))
    })
    @Embedded protected Address address;
    ...
}
```

In your case it would look like this

```
@Entity
public class Event {
    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name="code", column=@Column(name="manager_code"))
    public Person manager;

    @Embedded
    @AttributeOverride(name="code", column=@Column(name="operator_code"))
    public Person operator;

    //...
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me as I have two instances of the same `@Embeddable` class, not two different as in your example.

Comment: Looking at edit dates, it appears the answer has been rectified to deal with the preceding comment

Comment: I think that it is not necessary to write `@AttributeOverrides`. That also works writting DIRECTLY all the `@AttributeOverride`.

Comment: Confirming above comment is correct. Since Java 8 there is no longer any need to use the @AttributeOverrides wrapper