# JPA: how to override ONLY the column names of @Embedded attributes

Tags: java, jpa

This is an extension of [JPA: how to override column names of @Embedded attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36571347/jpa-how-to-override-column-names-of-embedded-attributes) but I only want to override the column names but keep everything else the same including `nullable` and `columnDefinition`

At present I have to copy and paste all the `@Column` settings from the field in the embedded object.  I am trying to find a way to not repeat myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not possible. Because JPA overwrites the Column annotation from the AttributeOverride.

You should open a feature request for Hibernate (or whatever JPA implementation you are using).